# "IT" oder "EDV"? Empfindet man "IT" als Anglizismus?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, loanword

Wenn es um *IT* geht, finde ich es immer schwer *EDV* zu benutzen (oder verstehen). Es fällt mir einfach nicht ein.

Mein Frage ist: **empfindet man *IT* als Anglizismus?** Sollte ich anstreben *EDV* zu sagen/schreiben oder ist *IT* schon anerkannt?

Nach [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=IT%2CEDV&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=) verbreitet sich *IT* immer mehr.

---

Kommentare:

- Ja, ich weiß, dass *IT* und *EDV* nicht **ganz** gleich sind, aber sie sind mehr oder weniger Synonyme.
- Ich weiß auch, dass *IT* per definitionem ein Anglizismus **ist**.

Comment: "Informationstechnik" ist ein Anglizismus? Ich würde sagen, dass, wenn es ausgesprochen wird, es davon abhängt, ob es dt. oder englisch ausgesprochen wird. Wenn geschrieben kann man es sich aussuchen.

Comment: Kommt auf den Standpunkt an. Für meinen Vater ist _IT_ ein Anglizismus ... und _EDV_ ist ein Fremdwort ;-)

Comment: @userunknown: Wie sagt man IT? "Ei Ti", nicht? Deshalb glaub(t)e ich, IT ist "ein Wort der englischen Sprache als Fremd- oder Lehnwort in einer anderen Sprache" (Anglizismus nach Wiktionary)

Comment: @Cucu Ich kenne IT auch als "I-Te", also deutsch ausgesprochen. Ich selbst begann in der EDV, war dann IS-ler (Informationssystem) und bin inzwischen IT-ler (englisch ausgesprochen). Aber mein Tätigkeitsbereich selbst hat sich kaum geändet - halt "irgendwas mit Computer" ;).

Answer (score 4):

Da IT einen weiteren Bereich abdeckt als EDV wäre es sicher befremdlich EDV dort zu verwenden wo das ganze Spektrum IT gemeint ist. Zumal sich IT in der direkten Übersetzung weder vom Sinn noch von der Schreibweise ändert. Auf Anglizismen komplett zu verzichten für zudem teilweise zu unglücklichen Formulierungen wie Mutterbrett o.ä.

Comment: Das Motherboard hieß noch zu Zeiten der "EDV" früher mal "Hauptplatine", ganz ohne Anglizismus oder lustige Übersetzungsfehler ;)

Comment: @Takkat: Als Fehler würde ich "Mutterplatine" nicht betrachten. In anderen Bereichen dient die Mutter ja auch als Metapher, etwa beim Mutterschiff. Auf Englisch bedeutet es auch nichts anderes, oder wofür steht "mother"?

Answer (score 4):

IT (sprich Ei Ti) ist natürlich kein Anglizismus, sondern einfach nur ein Fremdwort, oder vielmehr eine Abkürzung dafür. Und um die kommst du in der Ei Ti sowieso nicht drumherum. Ich kenne auch niemanden, der diese Abkürzung deutsch ausspricht - natürlich würde es ebenso passen, aber in der Regel wird dann doch eher der Begriff EDV verwendet, wenn man es deutsch haben möchte.

Sagst du immer Rechner oder auch mal Computer? In letzterem Fall passt IT doch auch ;)

Comment: Also ich sage zwar Ei Ti, aber wenn ich es ausspreche "Informationstechnologie(n)"

Comment: @Sentry: IT heißt (auch) Informationstechnik und bezeichnet dann die entsprechende Abteilung. Und dann rede ich doch eher von *der IT* und nicht von *der Informationstechnik*, wenn ich dieselbe meine. Besser wäre natürlich Informationstechnikabteilung ;)

Comment: Ich wollte ja nur darauf hinweisen, dass man sehr wohl die Abkürzung englisch, aber das Wort selbst deutsch aussprechen kann. Siehe PC, da ist es sogar umgekehrt.